# MAPI: Most efficient way to iterate through all the folders and items in a mailbox

Tags: performance, exchange-server, mapi, outlook-redemption

I'm trying to index items inside an exchange mailbox so: What is the most efficient way to iterate through all the folders and items in an exchange mailbox using MAPI and/or Redemption Data Objects (RDO)?

I know RDOFolder.GetAllChildFolders (and IMAPIContainer::GetHierarchyTable) can give me all the folders (probably in the most efficient way) but what about the items inside the folders?

Answer (score 2):

What are you going to do with the items? If you just want to read some properties, MAPI tables (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm) in Redemption (I am its author) is the way to go, and `RDOFolder.Items.MAPITable.ExecSQL` is probably the easiest to retrieve the data.
If you need to retrieve large string or binary properties, attachments, or modify the data, you have no choice but to open each item separately.

Comment: I want to read the the following properties
PR_LONGTERM_ENTRYID_FROM_TABLE, PR_ENTRYID, PR_STORE_ENTRYID, PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT_W, PR_MESSAGE_SIZE, PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME,
PR_CREATION_TIME

Comment: Can I do 1 RDOFolder.Items.MAPITable.ExecSQL to give me all the items in the mailbox?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.